# Microsoft Access 2010 loads slowly every time

Tags: microsoft-access

More in hope than expectation ... I've lived for some time now with the fact that Access 2010 takes a minute or two to load on my laptop.  The problem is to do with the fact that I've also got Access 2003 and 2007 loaded too (we're a training company, so I needed these).  I've now removed Access 2003, but have still got the same problem.  I've tried all sorts of things, as recommended by other sites, including registry changes.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess buying a better laptop with more memory, a recent high power CPU and an ssd  is out of the question? Are you disk bound or CPU bound?

Comment: Was there a time where your Microsoft Access opens up noticeable faster?

Answer (score 3):

The issue as noted is not the slow load. Suggestions here about indexing or defrag can be ignored.

Even on a weaker laptop, Access loads for me with little if any delay.

It is a WIDE known problem and A WELL KNOWN that the re-configuring and re-installing menu you see is a COMMON issue when you have multiple versions of office installed. This is not even limited to Access.

The issue is NOT slow load, but this dialog that appears during loading:

[image]

The above will occur even if you have a SSD drive.

And as noted, this issue is NOT limited to JUST Access. The basic issue here is that many applications and even including the inter-op assemblies for .net use late binding. If you have two versions of word (or Access) installed, then when you create an instance of

Word.Application
Or
Access.Application

Then what version of the installed application do you get when you attempt to create an instance of some office program?

So the "long delay" is in fact the office bits and parts being re-registered for the given version of office. There is  TRUCK LOAD of references to be changed.

Even if you cache Access 2003 and 2010 in ram – you find this delay.

Note:

The delay ONLY occurs when you re-launch a DIFFERENT version. And you MUST NOT launch + run both at the same time.

So if you launch 2010, get past delay, then additional loads are instant and without delay.

So as noted, the delay is ONLY when re-registering and re-pointing of the office application (in this case Access) to be set as the "default" version for automation.

So the if the LAST version of whatever office product you run was NOT the last version, then the long delay and long re-registration will occur. Of course, once you switch, then additional loading of the application is near instant.

Solutions:

If you really must work with multiple versions of office and you OFTEN have to switch, then you get hit with that close to 45 or near 60 second delay, then I suggest you use Virtual Pc and install separate versions into that.

I have 2003 and 2010, and since I don't switch every day, then I am ok with this one time delay. However, if you supporting multiple versions on your one box, then I suggest VPC or even windows XP mode – it works great, removes the delay, and you can even run both at once.

Comment: If only Albert Kallal's answer were true! I get the problem every time I load Access 2010, not just the first time I switch after loading a different version.

Comment: Then uninstall and reinstall, or do a Repair !

Answer (score 0):

Defragmenting, turning off file indexation and reducing the number of running applications at the time MS Access is run might help your case.
also, tried to clean "things up a bit" with [Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) ?

Comment: Znau's answer will make my computer quicker, but won't affect this problem.